# How to save all companions in the House at the End of Time?

Tags: pathfinder-kingmaker

Towards the end of the game, in the "House at the End of Time", you have to save your companions. Chance of saving them seems to depend on the resolutions of their personal quests:

### Spoilers ahead

- **Amiri**: In act 4 (Twice Born Warlord) I've done the "Hour of Rage" first, saving most of the barbarians and most important her friend. Later on, when her tribe was held hostage by a ghost giant, Amiri sacrificed herself, after I've asked her to sacrifice me instead (she got better).
- **Valerie**: In the prologue, I've helped her taking care of wounded soldiers; won a duel with her old master (damn, damn hard fight!!!) and let him go. When she was acting up, I've convinced her to calm down and apologize. During her judgement, she apologized and was forgiven by the goddess (her scar disappeared)
- **Harim**: here my memory is a bit fuzzy: let him destroy the magical anvil, then the same with golem. In the last quest, I've sided with the dwarves and destroyed the magical throne. I'm not sure about the consequences of the conversation afterwards, but he accepted the fact, that he is not cursed (but he still follows his god of destruction).
- **Octavia**: Not much to decide here: When I found the Technical League hideout, I let her old master run away and saved the slaves. Later on, I've visited her mother in Pitax (I don't think that I had to convince Octavia to forgive her or anything).
- **Regognar**: The same quest as Octavia - I let his old slavemaster to run away and saved the slaves. When found his tribe, I've buried the bones.

Not sure is it important here: I was romancing Octavia but after the first meeting I didn't reply with "I love you too" (I was still able to keep sleeping with her!), so in the ending I didn't have any suggestion, that I was still with her - instead, it was information, that Regognar was thinking about proposing himself.

- **Jubilost**: won the fey competition without hurting anyone. When meeting the Host again, Jubilost decided to give immortality to some random, dying ("bleaching") gnome, who saved him in the end.
- **Ekundayo**: I let the kid-trolls go in act 1, I told him it is time to stop his vengeance and find new bury his past, siding with the tavernkeeper. In the House, when facing near-unkillable troll, I simply walked away with him in my group (I didn't have to convince him to walk away, even while it was in the options, I just said "we will kill it"... and I didn't :P)

Unfortunately, I was unable to save Jaethal and Nok-Nok (and to a degree Tristan):

- **Nok-Nok**: I let him build his temples, but when facing the false Goblin King, I simply killed him instead of tricking him. This made Nok-Nok doubt, that he is a hero, so he was killed in the House.
- **Tristan**: I forgave him, followed his quest chasing the monster-cult. In the end, I've saved the final sacrifice, but after Tristan was forgiven by his goddess, I've said "do what you want" and he became a deva (but still stayed with me). In the House, he says that "he has been deceived again" and killed Jaethal.
- **Jaethal**: Most problems here: I've convinced her to kill the undead girl she just created, then I've learned the magic ritual and kept my word and risen the old priestess. In the showdown with elves, I let the inquisitor kill her daughter. I was trying to convince her to stop, but I couldn't, so the only options were either sacrifice the daughter, possess her body or attack Jaethal. I let her decide and she has chosen the sacrifice. In the House, she is convinced, that she must kill Tristan.

So, with that long wall of text (that I hope will be helpful to someone), can you tell me, how to save all companions and bring most positive endings?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I've managed to save them all:

- **Nok-Nok** - apparently you can go "hero" or "jester" way, I've chosen the former. First killed the giant at Oleg's post, then let him keep the shrines. When he is challenged by the "king", you need to pass a test that will enrage the barghest and **then** kill it. You'll know that you've done it right if the goblins around you will start clapping. Afterwards, in your capital name Nok-Nok the official hero of your kingdom.
- **Tristan** - don't chase the escaping cultists, when you have to choose his fate, tell him to stay mortal, save the final sacrifice. Apparently it helps to bring Jaethal to the last quest (dealing with the last cultists)
- **Jaethal** - I let the undead girl die, I didn't take the hag's deal but I've sided with Jaethal against her killer. When meeting with her daughter, I've managed to convince Jaethal to spare her (bringing Tristan to this mission helps). Jaethal exploded but returned in the House.

Answer (score 0):

My very first and (so far) only run, i only lost Jubilost and Linzi. I had used his wish to save the mad gnome trying to open a door to the first world, and apparently that doesn't save him. Doesn't make sens how a random gnome in the real world would save him in the house, where the actual gnome in the first world would not, but ok.

It seems you are mainly wondering about Jaethal. I turned the girl undead, and i kept her as a servant. Later I took the scroll and betrayed the witch, letting her die. But when i found the daughter, i convinced Jaethal to spare her (I had skill focus persuasion on a charismatic sorcerer, and also a couple of other bonuses like trickster i believe so it was a very high persuasion score), which angered her goddess and she died right there. I thought she was lost, but when i got to the house, she was revived by another goddess (the enemy of her former goddess) so she ended up living in the end.

She did seem to fight tristan before i arrived, but none of them died. This could be affected by other decisions but i don't know exactly what.

Comment: Linzi's fate is sealed and you can't change it. Jubilost's gift of immortality goes to the gnome who was at the Inconsequential Debates - you fight (and kill) her later in the Menagerie location (she keeps sending monsters to your kingdom), but she is revived as Fey and saves you in the end. She also stops the fight between you and her two brothers in the Iorvetti's palace